# As an administrator, configure Singularity to redirect paths to local repositories

Tags: hpc, singularity-container

I'm new to Singularity and especially to it as an administrator. I have local servers or cached files for various packages like `apt` or python `pip`. Is there a way to ensure that Singularity automatically redirects  `apt install` or `pip install` or something else to the local resources during build stages?

I've built a Singularity Container based on Ubuntu 20.04 and redirected the paths inside the container to the resources, but this seems like a bad way to do it.